# How to use images using path from json file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

In my project I have a state and I wanted to put it into the local json file, so I used

```
const jsonFile = JSON.stringify(this.state);
```

and logged it in the console. So I just created a json file in `public` folder and used it as a local storage for state. Just for the sake of testing. So, by using `axios` I wanted to get the data from `json` file and use it to `setState`.

The problem comes with images. The original name of the image is "photo.png" but in json file the path is written like `/static/media/photo.206df5b0.png`. And when I start React project it gives me an error **`TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined`** which means that it does not see the file. I tried to rename these images and put them in other folders, but nothing worked for me

So, the question is how to use json path to images correctly?

Comment: Can i see more code please, this information is not sufficient.

Comment: yeah, I got it. My fault. But I have just solved my problem =) thanks anyway =)

Comment: @AnvarAbdulsatarov so please delete this question or post your solution